# Как отсортировать TreeMap по значению в порядке убывания?

Tags: java, android

здраствуйте , у меня есть вот такой  `TreeMap`

```
 final Map<String, String> scores2;
    scores2 = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

и в него поступают данные

```
 for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String koko = childSnapshot.child("koko").getValue(String.class);
                    String boko = childSnapshot.child("boko").getValue(String.class);
                    String moko = childSnapshot.child("moko").getValue(String.class);
                    String shoko = childSnapshot.child("shoko").getValue(String.class);
                    String lopo = childSnapshot.child("lopo").getValue(String.class);
                    String score = childSnapshot.child("score").getValue(String.class);

                    scores2.put("koko",koko);
                    scores2.put("boko",boko);
                    scores2.put("moko",moko);
                    scores2.put("shoko",shoko);
                    scores2.put("lopo",lopo);
                    scores2.put("score", score);

                }
```

как отсортировать TreeMap с большого `score` к маленькому ???

```
пример

до
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko " moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 81
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 91
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 92
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 91
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 89
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 82
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 89
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 82
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 84
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 88

после
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko " moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 92
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 92
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 91
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 89
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 89
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 88
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 84
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 82
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 82
    koko = "koko" boko = "boko" moko = "moko" lopo = "lopo " score = 81
```

Comment: изменил вопрос >>>>>>>

Comment: У вас значение в Map - это строка. Вы хотите по длине отсортировать?

Comment: я хочу чтобы отсортировка была по значению score и после  все значения сохранялись в  map илье list

Comment: TreeMap упорядочена по ключу, а не по значению. Помести значения в список и отсортируйте его.

Comment: можите дать кусок кода как это делать?

Answer (score 1):

Если для сортировки Values

```
 System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(scores2));

static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>> 
            List<Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {

    List<Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(sortedEntries, 
            new Comparator<Entry<K,V>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Entry<K,V> e1, Entry<K,V> e2) {
                    return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                }
            }
    );

    return sortedEntries;
}
```

Интерфейс Map соотносит ***уникальные*** ключи со значениями. Ключ - это объект, который вы используете для последующего извлечения данных. Задавая ключ и значение, вы можете помещать значения в объект отображения. После того как это значение сохранено, вы можете получить его по ключу.

Comment: а куда дать параметр scores2 ?

Comment: @David Kern поправил, попробуйте!

Comment: в newMap толка один объект с самым большим значением но куда подевались остальные объекты?

Comment: он проста изменил порядок  !!!

Comment: вы пробyвали  ?^%&%$^%&%&

Comment: он выдает только один объект а остальные куда то пропали

Comment: @David Kern вероятно что у вас ключи в map одинаковые, а одинаковые ключи накладываются друг на друга по умолчанию, у меня все работает на отлично

Comment: ok , конечно они одинаковые толка value изменяется

Comment: @David Kern, В Java map ключ должен быть уникален, иначе он затирается следующим!

Comment: ок а какое тогда может быть решение ?

Comment: функция которую вы указали она сортирует все значение по порадкy

Comment: мне надо : пример -> {name = "david",country="russia",score="97"},{name = "michael",country="france",score="94"},                                {name = "john",country="usa",score="92"},

Comment: как сделать в threemap , hashmap select where order by desc ???если возможно что то наподобие сделать??!!

Comment: @David Kern, попробуйте использовать JSON, вот ссылка на примеры, мне кажется данный вопрос можно закрыть, потому что мы перешли уже на другую тему http://goloburdin.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/json-java.html

Comment: я использую firebase json

Comment: @David Kern  Если хотите разобраться, можете прочесть литературу или уроки, примеры,  про "java hiberenate"